# Imacros How to Open a Link in a New Tab

Tags: javascript, extract, imacros

I am trying to get iMacros to open a link in a new tab. My current code is:

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ITEMPROP:name&&CLASS:product-card__description **EXTRACT=HTML**
TAB OPEN NEW
TAB T=2
**URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}**
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:"loading-spinner-btn button button--primary add-to-cart-button"
```

However when I run the code, it does everything except open the new tab with extracted URL in the `ITEMPROP` TAG. Please help, I will even donate to you through paypal if I can get this resolved.

**Note:** I have tried `extract=html/href/htm` none seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code might help you.

```
SET !TIMEOUT 200
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

TAB T=1

'This Extracts HREF by XPATH'
TAG XPATH="//div[@itemporp='name'][@class='product-card__description']//a[1]" EXTRACT=HREF
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
WAIT SECONDS=1

'Spaces in attributes has to be replaced by <SP>'
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:loading-spinner-btn<SP>button<SP>button--primary<SP>add-to-cart-button
```

I assumed there is link inside div tag which you are trying to extract and load in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround may be helpful:

```
TAB T=1
SET urlCopy {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO={{urlCopy}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ITEMPROP:name&&CLASS:product-card__description
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:"loading-spinner-btn button button--primary add-to-cart-button"
```

---

**Old info.**

 You can open a link in a new tab simply by means of the following code:

```
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT http://somesite.com
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
```

In your case, first of all play only this line:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ITEMPROP:name&&CLASS:product-card__description EXTRACT=HTM
```

and see whether there is a link that you need, displayed in the popup window among other html-tags. If yes, provide this html-code to get a final solution.

Comment: Ok this worked to obtain the extracted information from the link and it put it in Tab 2, however the extracted information was showing up as "<div style="outline: 1px solid blue;" class="product-card__description" itemprop="name"> Silk Gingham Dress </div>". This was put in the link so it was invalid. Is there a way to extract the link directly?

Comment: As you can see, no links are present in the extract. So try the updated macro. If it doesn't work, indicate the url of the page you're automating.

Comment: The url of the page im trying to extract is different for every item in the list. The items in the list also change every day. So i need it to obtain the link from the different itemprops that show up every day. The link is embedded into the items description and it only seems to pull out the DIV location and item POS and not the link that it goes to when clicked. Im offering $50 for a fix.

Comment: Additional info is needed in order to solve this issue. You may contact me via e-mail (see my profile page) and we'll try to fix it.